Proof that the distribution function is super uniform
Let $X$ be some real random variable defined on a probability space, let $F(x)= \mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$ be its distribution function. Then show that $\forall t \in [0,1]:$
$$\mathbb{P}(F(x) \leq t) \leq t $$ , i.e. $F(X)$ is super uniform.
I know that the distribution function is uniform Distribution Function is Uniform. Looking at the formula that we need to prove, it also wouldn't surprise me if valid $p$ values were involved.

This follows from the Inverse transform sampling and properties of the generalized inverse distribution function.
